# TabView selection restores to previous one after tapping on a different tab

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, swiftui-tabview

I'm encountering a strange behavior with `TabView`. In particular, I've created a UI with 4 different tabs. Every tab performs something different. The application starts with the first one selected.
Tapping on the third tab `FavoritesView` is created.

```
struct FavoritesView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = FavoritesViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        switch viewModel.viewState {
        case .idle:
            Color.red
                .onAppear {
                    Task {
                        try await viewModel.fetchBookmarks()
                    }
                }
        case .loading:
            ProgressView()
        case .failed(let error):
            Text(error.localizedDescription)
        case .finished(let newsLetters):
            if newsLetters.isEmpty {
                EmptyResultsView()
            } else {
                List(newsLetters) { newsLetter in
                    Text(newsLetter.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This `View` has a view model associated to it.

```
enum ViewState<Value> {
    case idle
    case loading
    case finished(Value)
    case failed(Error)
}

@MainActor
final class FavoritesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var viewState = ViewState<[NewsLetter]>.idle
    
    @Stored(in: .newsLetterStore) var newsLetters
    
    func fetchBookmarks() async throws {
        do {
            try await $newsLetters.itemsHaveLoaded()
            viewState = .finished($newsLetters.items)
        } catch {
            viewState = .failed(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Th fact is that, when `viewState = .finished($newsLetters.items)` is executed, the screen becomes red (due to `Color.red`) for just one second but the selection goes back to the first tab.
In order to open the third tab effectively I must tap on it a second time.
Commenting out `viewState =` the behavior is the one I expected. The screen remains red.

Any hint on that? I'm wrapping my head around but I cannot find a solution.

**UPDATE**

Here you can find a sample repo where is possible to replicate the same behavior I've described.

https://github.com/flexaddicted/sample-bug

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for your reply. I've updated the question with the repo where is possible to replicate the behavior.

Comment: No problem, hopefully someone else will be willing to download. I don’t download code from repos, I answer questions as a distraction and to help the many, links to repos don’t help the many. MREs should be included in questions with emphasis on Minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the repo, I can see that you don't have `.tag` defined on `tabItem`.

This generally results in selection switching to the first tab after changes in view model.

Whether that is a feature or a bug in SwiftUI is hard to tell, but you can certainly resolve it by adding that.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Are you able to share any doc to describe such a behavior?

Comment: @LorenzoB I don’t think that there is the document on that, but I have noticed that problem while developing the app. Anyway, it is trivial to try, did you try it and did it help?

Comment: I've tried and it works. It could really be a bug. Thanks for your support.